# How to solve the problem of missing CA files during Gitlab installation？

Tags: docker, gitlab

I encountered the following problem when installing gitlab, all services are running, but I can't access the home page through the browser, and I checked the log message and found an error message indicating that the ca.crt file could not be found

```
run: alertmanager: (pid 26351) 624s; run: log: (pid 4641) 2149s
run: gitaly: (pid 26406) 623s; run: log: (pid 4638) 2149s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 26515) 622s; run: log: (pid 4630) 2149s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 26517) 622s; run: log: (pid 4633) 2149s
run: grafana: (pid 26650) 622s; run: log: (pid 4634) 2149s
run: logrotate: (pid 26675) 621s; run: log: (pid 4629) 2149s
run: nginx: (pid 26794) 621s; run: log: (pid 4637) 2149s
run: node-exporter: (pid 26894) 620s; run: log: (pid 4636) 2149s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 27009) 620s; run: log: (pid 4628) 2149s
run: postgresql: (pid 27018) 619s; run: log: (pid 4640) 2149s
run: prometheus: (pid 27021) 619s; run: log: (pid 4642) 2149s
run: puma: (pid 27082) 618s; run: log: (pid 4639) 2149s
run: redis: (pid 27105) 618s; run: log: (pid 4631) 2149s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 27135) 617s; run: log: (pid 4632) 2149s
run: sidekiq: (pid 27287) 614s; run: log: (pid 4635) 2149s
```

The log messages are as follows:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/prometheus/current <==
2021-08-26_08:53:49.90252 level=info ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.902Z caller=main.go:802 msg="TSDB started"
2021-08-26_08:53:49.90253 level=info ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.902Z caller=main.go:928 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml
2021-08-26_08:53:49.90450 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.904Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-08-26_08:53:49.90467 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.904Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-08-26_08:53:49.90470 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.904Z caller=manager.go:314 component="discovery manager scrape" msg="Cannot create service discovery" err="unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" type=kubernetes
2021-08-26_08:53:49.91260 level=info ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.912Z caller=main.go:959 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=10.013055ms remote_storage=2.512µs web_handler=754ns query_engine=1.237µs scrape=76.398µs scrape_sd=490.692µs notify=27.166µs notify_sd=19.689µs rules=7.607982ms
2021-08-26_08:53:49.91262 level=info ts=2021-08-26T08:53:49.912Z caller=main.go:751 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
2021-08-26_08:53:54.91465 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:54.914Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating new scrape pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-nodes
2021-08-26_08:53:54.91483 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:54.914Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating new scrape pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-cadvisor
2021-08-26_08:53:54.91549 level=error ts=2021-08-26T08:53:54.914Z caller=manager.go:188 component="scrape manager" msg="error creating new scrape pool" err="error creating HTTP client: unable to load specified CA cert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory" scrape_pool=kubernetes-pods
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab 15.5 shows HTTP 500, so I run the

> gitlab-ctl reconfigure

and error disappeared.